# auto.arima outputting zero values as output in R

Tags: r, arima

I was playing around with auto.arima function and did the following in R:

```
forecast(auto.arima(ts(c(1:4))), h=12)
```

The output was just constant.

```
   Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
             0     -3.509674 3.509674 -5.367582 5.367582
```

Is there a problem with the way I wrote the ARIMA code? I have no idea where 0 came from. I was expecting 5, 6, 7, ..., 16 as output vector yet I got something totally different.

Comment: @李哲源 yes, but I just didn't know why auto.arima outputs 0 as forecast output even when there's a perfect trend in the time series I constructed. Is there a way to change it using ARIMA?

Comment: @李哲源 how do you make ARIMA detect a trend when there are fewer than 5 data points?